# How to query the MessageCount of the $DeadLetterQueue in Azure Service Bus?

Tags: azure, servicebus, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm trying to get the count of messages in both the queue and the DeadLetterQueue.  The regular queue works.  The dead letter doesn't.

This Works:

```
NamespaceManager
.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString)
.GetQueue(queueName)
.MessageCount;
```

This Fails:

```
NamespaceManager
.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString)
.GetQueue(queueName + "/$DeadLetterQueue")
.MessageCount;
```

The error message is (edited):

```
System.ArgumentException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. 
The specified HTTP verb (GET) is not valid.
```

Is this just not possible?

Answer (score 2):

Use the .MessageCountDetails property rather than .MessageCount. MessageCountDetails has a number of count properties one of which is the DLQ.